# full width wave in CSS, SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am building a website, it has a part that is in wave form, like this:
[PSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4gz9.png)

I am currently using the PSD image, a PNG, to put on the site, but I would like the wave to have full width of the screen, 
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypBId.png)

I would like a CSS solution, so I researched a bit, and talez is possible using SVG, however I do not I succeeded in creating

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 25">
  <path fill="#9EAFFD" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: post some code you trying

Comment: o added the code on post

Comment: You shouldn't change the question after it has been answered in such a way that it makes the answer invalid, otherwise we could end up never getting to an answer. If you have another question about having a different picture entirely displayed, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add a wrapper for the SVGs
2. Add preserveAspectRatio="none" to every one of the SVGs elements
3. Add position absolute with 100% width and hight to the SVG elements

Like the following:

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 25" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="#9EAFFD" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
  </svg>
```

CSS

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.svg-wrapper{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
.svg-wrapper svg{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To get multiple instances of waves, you can use [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) in which there will be one wave.

We select the width and height of the pattern equal to the width and height of one wave `width = "100"` and `height = "25"`

Fill the rectangular area with a `pattern`. With `viewBox = "0 0 100 25"` the pattern will fit once.

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 100 25">
 <defs>
      <pattern id="Wave"
             x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
            <path d="M0 25 0 6C20 9 38 11 55 7 72 4 87 4 100 6l0 19z" id="path4" fill="#9eaffd"/>
      </pattern>
   </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Wave)" />
</svg>
```

To get 4 waves, you need the pattern to fit four times the length. To do this, increase `width` four times -`viewBox = "0 0 400 25"`

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 400 25">
 <defs>
      <pattern id="Wave"
             x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
            <path d="M0 25 0 6C20 9 38 11 55 7 72 4 87 4 100 6l0 19z" id="path4" fill="#9eaffd"/>
      </pattern>
   </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Wave)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson I agree with you that it is very wrong to change the question when an answer has already been given. I hope the beginner will not do so in the future. Very much has changed both in the question and in the comments since I gave the answer. The author of the question wrote in the commentary that he wants to get 4 waves.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry for changing the content of the post, but I did it only once because a user asked me to add my code, I was wrong to edit the post when I should make a new comment ... But you keep repeating this over and over again , why do not you simply stop contributing?

Comment: @Alexandr_T Almost there, in fact I do not want to get 4 waves in a single line, but I want to have 4 wavelines, one overlapping the other, just like in the photo I posted, 
In my defense, I posted this image from the beginning and never edited, the only part I edited was to add the code to the post